# What happens if someone pretends to be a users' sock puppet?

Tags: support, account-suspension, duplicate-accounts

On SO, creating [sock puppets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)) will get you suspended. But the question is, what if someone creates a fake account and acts like a decoy, e.g. he or she up-votes all of your Q&A, and it will appear to the mods that your account is intensely having voting irregularities; will they find out that the fake user purposely did this just to get the other user suspended, or will they proceed upon arguably agreeing that this user created a sock puppet just to earn some reputation, and suspend the user?

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic because it not about a real problem that was encountered on Stack Overflow. If you encounter an actual problem, please post a new question.

Comment: Pfft. It's an example of a general sock puppet situation, that's not new ... but it is rare.

Comment: It is *not* an example of "a general sock puppet situation". It's a contrived scenario, an example of something that has never happened, is not currently a problem, and that there is no reason to believe ever will become one.

Comment: Anyone can easily do this, and even suspend the most reputable users on SO. Simple. They up-vote all of your Q&A, then you appear to be suspicious about creating a sock puppet. I was just curious as to how this situation will be [handled.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685)

Comment: What you mean is that you *imagine* anyone could *hypothetically* easily do this, and then that it would have your *imagined* consequence. It doesn't work that way. The situation doesn't have to be handled because it doesn't happen.

Comment: Alright, I was a bit too specific on that example, however I just wanted to know more about sock puppets on SO, and how they are handled. For example, this specific situation may lead to many other forms of sock puppet situations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[They run a good chance of getting their fake account deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685).

Comment: But do they get suspended? (The actual user)

Comment: Maybe. This is pretty rare, and of course, I wouldn't discuss specific instances. But as a general rule, playing silly games that make more work for others does tend to get one suspended.

Comment: Right, and of course, they can contact one of the mods and discuss the problem, correct?

Comment: Of course. Any time there's a suspension or suspicion, a moderator will have sent a private message, which can be responded to.

Comment: @WEB_UI: Let's put it this way: It's _not possible_ for one user (A) to get another user (B) suspended, Aside from A reporting something B did wrong.

Comment: @WEB_UI - To Cerbrus' point, I talk about the situation of someone trying to get another user suspended [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338836/19679): "People sometimes seem to think that they can pull the equivalent of "SWATting" someone by intentionally serially upvoting an innocent person in an attempt to get them suspended, but that won't do anything. We weren't born yesterday."